# Not able to access the Assigned To field of a Azure DevOps Work Item

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, workitem

I am creating a console application in visual studio to get the work item details from a Azure DevOps project. I am not able to access the `AssignedTo` field of a Work item.

I tried using the code in Microsoft page to query work items with some changes and Its showing a exception when I try to access the `AssignedTo` field.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string _uri = "https://dev.azure.com/xyz";
     string _personalAccessToken = 
     "xpdrix7nyspotj3l4gotvvk4cpp2z6l65g5r";
     string _project = "FirstProject";
     Uri uri = new Uri(_uri);
     string personalAccessToken = _personalAccessToken;
     string project = _project;

     VssBasicCredential credentials = new VssBasicCredential("", 
     _personalAccessToken);

     //create a wiql object and build our query
     Wiql wiql = new Wiql()
     {
         Query = "Select *" +
                 "From WorkItems " +
                 "Where [System.TeamProject] = '" + project + "' " +
                  "Order By [State] Asc, [Changed Date] Desc"
     };

     //create instance of work item tracking http client
      sing (WorkItemTrackingHttpClient workItemTrackingHttpClient = 
      new WorkItemTrackingHttpClient(uri, credentials))
      {
         //execute the query to get the list of work items in the results 
         WorkItemQueryResult workItemQueryResult = 
         workItemTrackingHttpClient.QueryByWiqlAsync(wiql).Result;

         //some error handling                
         if (workItemQueryResult.WorkItems.Count() != 0)
         {
             //need to get the list of our work item id's and put them 
             //into an array
             List<int> list = new List<int>();
             foreach (var item in workItemQueryResult.WorkItems)
             {
                 list.Add(item.Id);
             }
             int[] arr = list.ToArray();

             //build a list of the fields we want to see
             string[] fields = new string[3];
             fields[0] = "System.Id";
             fields[1] = "System.Title";
             fields[2] = "System.AssignedTo";
             WorkItemExpand workItemExpand = WorkItemExpand.All;

             //get work items for the id's found in query
             var workItems = 
             workItemTrackingHttpClient.GetWorkItemsAsync(arr, fields=null, workItemQueryResult.AsOf,workItemExpand).Result;

             Console.WriteLine("Query Results: {0} items found", workItems.Count);

             //loop though work items and write to console
             foreach (var workItem in workItems)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}", workItem.Id, workItem.Fields["System.Title"], workItem.Fields["System.AssignedTo"]);
             }

          }
       }
    }
}
```

The error is:

> System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException
>     HResult=0x80131577
>     Message=The given key was not present in the dictionary.
>     Source=mscorlib
>     StackTrace:
>     at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
>     at ScrumBoard.Program.Main(String[] args) in 
>     C:\Users\Naresh\source\repos\ScrumBoard\ScrumBoard\Program.cs:line 84

Comment: Can you mask your PAT, not a good idea to put it online with everyone to see

Comment: Thats a invalid PAT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException` exception will be thrown out if the `assigned to` field is Unassigned.

Please check if the `assigned to` field is assigned in your queried work item.

You code is Ok, Except i cannot compile `workItemQueryResult.WorkItems.Count()`, I casted it to IList<> instead. `((IList<WorkItemReference>)workItemQueryResult.WorkItems).Count()`

[image]

Comment: Yea the exception is gone after I changed a work item assigned to field from Unassigned. But I am getting a reference in the console output instead of the display Name or who the work item is assigned. I am getting Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.IdentityRef

Comment: You need to Convert it to JObject first. For example:
`JObject identity = JObject.FromObject(workItem.Fields["System.AssignedTo"]);
                        
Console.WriteLine(identity["DisplayName"]);`

Comment: Thank you ,that worked. Is there anyway I can include assignedto field if the workitems are Unassigned

Comment: i am afraid this can only be done in the code. the code below is for example

Comment: `workItem.Fields.TryGetValue("System.AssignedTo", out Object identityOjbect);
                      
                        if (identityOjbect == null)
                        {
                             identityOjbect = new { DisplayName = "Unassigned" };
                         }

                        JObject identity = JObject.FromObject(identityOjbect);
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}   {1}    {2}", workItem.Id, workItem.Fields["System.Title"], identity["DisplayName"]);`

Answer (score 0):

It's because when you get the work items you specify `fields = null`.

You need just to give the id's without any additional parameters:

```
var workItems = workItemTrackingHttpClient.GetWorkItemsAsync(arr).Result;
```

Now you will get all the fields including `System.AssignedTo`.

Comment: Still the same exception comes and the code above in the question is able to print other fields if I remove the assigned to field

Answer (score 0):

This was the new code:

```
static void Main(string[] arg
 {
       
        string _uri = "https://dev.azure.com/xyz";
        string _personalAccessToken = 
       "xpdrix7nyspotj3l4gotvvk4cpp2z6l65g5rd4pfbrl7nskq";
        string _project = "FirstProject";

        /// <summary>
        /// Execute a WIQL query to reutnr a list of bugs using the .NET client library
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>List of Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi.Models.WorkItem</returns>

        Uri uri = new Uri(_uri);
        string personalAccessToken = _personalAccessToken;
        string project = _project;

        VssBasicCredential credentials = new VssBasicCredential("", _personalAccessToken);

        //create a wiql object and build our query
        Wiql wiql = new Wiql()
        {
            Query = "Select *" +
                    "From WorkItems " +
                    
                    "Where [System.TeamProject] = '" + project + "' " +
                   
                    "Order By [State] Asc, [Changed Date] Desc"
        };

        //create instance of work item tracking http client
        using (WorkItemTrackingHttpClient workItemTrackingHttpClient = new WorkItemTrackingHttpClient(uri, credentials))
        {
            //execute the query to get the list of work items in teh results
            WorkItemQueryResult workItemQueryResult = workItemTrackingHttpClient.QueryByWiqlAsync(wiql).Result;

            //some error handling                
            if (workItemQueryResult.WorkItems.Count() != 0)
            {
                //need to get the list of our work item id's and put them into an array
                List<int> list = new List<int>();
                foreach (var item in workItemQueryResult.WorkItems)
                {
                    list.Add(item.Id);
                }
                int[] arr = list.ToArray();

            
                
                

                //get work items for the id's found in query
                var workItems = workItemTrackingHttpClient.GetWorkItemsAsync(arr).Result;

                Console.WriteLine("Query Results: {0} items found", workItems.Count);

                //loop though work items and write to console
                foreach (var workItem in workItems)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}          {1}                     {2}", workItem.Id, workItem.Fields["System.Title"], workItem.Fields["System.AssignedTo"]);
                }


            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```